# How to run Cypress headed tests using Chrome Incognito

Tags: google-chrome, automation, cypress, incognito-mode

I run my tests using the below synbtax. The issue i see is my organization is has extensions that block chrome headed tests from running. The tests run smooth headless using chrome but get blocked when they run headed using chrome. I am wondering if there is a way to run chrome headed using incognito.

`npx cypress run --browser chrome --headed`

Comment: how about you pass the flag `--incognito` and check if this works or not ?

Comment: @AlapanDas - I tried this npx cypress run --browser chrome --headed --incognito and i get and error saying incognito is an unknown option

Answer (score 2):

I have used cypress and I ran my cypress test runner in incognito mode. All you need to do is to provide the below code in your index.js file inside the plugins folder of cypress.

```
 module.exports = (on, config) => {
 
   on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {
     console.log(launchOptions.args);
     if (browser.name === "chrome") {
       launchOptions.args.push("--incognito");
     }
     return launchOptions;
   });
 };
```

Reference for the same: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Plugin-Event-before-browser-launch

Answer (score 2):

Within the cypress\plugins\index.js file put this code:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
            launchOptions.args.push("--incognito");                
            return launchOptions
        }

        if (browser.name === 'electron') {                
            launchOptions.preferences.incognito = true               
            return launchOptions
        }
    })    
}
```