# How to setup Cypress to run a headed test in Edge in incognito/private mode?

Tags: cypress, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run a test case in Cypress in a headed Edge browser.

How do I set-up this test to run Edge in Incognito/Private mode?

I've found an example using Chrome: [How to run Cypress headed tests using Chrome Incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896471/how-to-run-cypress-headed-tests-using-chrome-incognito)

but not Edge.

The way start/run the test is with the command: npx cypress run.

Once Cypress open i click on the Edge Option, then it opens the Edge in headed mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more or less the same, but the flag you need is `--inprivate`
The following should work:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        // `args` is an array of all the arguments that will
        // be passed to browsers when it launches
        console.log(launchOptions.args) // print all current args

        if (browser.name === 'edge') {
          // open in incognito
          launchOptions.args.push('--inprivate')
        }

        // whatever you return here becomes the launchOptions
        return launchOptions
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I tried your option and the others (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896471/how-to-run-cypress-headed-tests-using-chrome-incognito) but the browser does not open in incognito/private. I may be doing something wrong, I added the suggested config inside cypress/plugins/index.js, and still no success.

Comment: I kind of mix-and-match your solution. The corporation blocks Edge Private, but not Chrome. With your template with Chrome in the cypress.config it worked.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but I need to be sure, are you trying to open the Browser in Incognito/Private or headless?

Comment: Browser in Incognito/Private