# Cypress Test Authentication with Azure AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, cypress

I am trying to test an Azure AAD Login with Cypress.

I tried to follow the steps from: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication

If I navigate to the home page with the following:

```
describe('Azure Active Directory Authentication', () => {
  it('should verify the user logged in has the correct name', () => {
    cy.visit('/home')
  })
})
```

Then Cypress gets stuck in the Azure Login:
[image]

Now when I use the cy.origin:

```
describe('Azure Active Directory Authentication', () => {
    it('should verify the user logged in has the correct name', () => {
      cy.visit('/home')
      const username = 'juanito'

      cy.origin(
          'login.microsoftonline.com',
          {args: {username}},
          ({ username }) => {
            console.log("HELELLOOO: " + username)
          }
      )
    })
})
```

The Login Page pops-up and after a few seconds it moves straight in the page behind the authentication. Looks to me Cypress/Browser is using some previously stored data, because it is bypassing the AZ Login.

I tried to clear the browser, reinstalled the npm packages, tried Cypress.session.clearAllSavedSessions() and Cypress.session.clearCurrentSessionData(), but with no success.

How do I fix this issue and make sure Cypress authenticate first with Azure AAD then moves into the pages behind the login?

[image]

Comment: Try with Electron. I had similar problems with Chrome, it turns out that my company's policies interfered with Chrome. It might be that your Chrome is managed by your organization or you are behind a proxy.

Comment: I tried with Chrome, Edge and Electron they are all having the same behaviour. Firefox does not work for me, it does not open.

Answer (score 0):

I triggered a Chrome/Incognito session, Edge/Private is blocked by my corporation.

I set in the cypress.config.ts the configuration suggested by @guzmanoj in [How to setup Cypress to run a headed test in Edge in incognito/private mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178022/how-to-setup-cypress-to-run-a-headed-test-in-edge-in-incognito-private-mode/76178118#76178118)

instead of Edge, I used:

```
 if (browser.name === "chrome") {
    launchOptions.args.push("--incognito");                
 }
```